# Npgsql 2.2.7 doesn`t read the "inet" type data value if it contain mask equal to 32

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have a legacy MFC application, which I should re-write on C#.
The MFC application has read data from a PostgreSql database which contains an inet-type column with masks, for example:

`233.81.116.0/32`, `233.255.116.20/16`, etg.

In C# I have used the Npgsql library and when I tried to read this inet-type column, the Npgsql throw an exception

> Cannot cast CIDR network to address" for "233.255.116.20/16" value.

Have you any ideas for reading this values?

Comment: Any particular reason to use Npgsql 2.2.7 and not 3.0.4?

Comment: The C# application should work on Windows XP with .NET 4.0. And the Npgsql v.3 works on .NET4.5.

Comment: The code
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("select ip_range from iptv.iptv_acls", conn);
    NpgsqlParameter firstColumn = new NpgsqlParameter("ip_range", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
      firstColumn.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
      command.Parameters.Add(firstColumn);            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(firstColumn.Value);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ;
            }
            conn.Close(); reads the value properly, but the first value from the set only

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue until I upgraded my npgsql package to the latest version. As my code was in a dll, I also had to make sure to add the 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions' package to the project using my dll after I upgraded npgsql.

In order to get the full ip address (cidr and all) as a string, I used this call

```
    public string GetInetValue(NpgsqlDataReader dr, string columnName, String defaultValue)
    {
        var returnVal = defaultValue;
        try
        {
            returnVal = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal(columnName)) ? defaultValue : dr.GetFieldValue<String>(dr.GetOrdinal(columnName));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
```